# How to get use Facebook Api unread count notification in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Guys.

I want get unread count notification in Android.

But, I can't get that:(

My facebook API version is 2.5 
facebook API 2.5 not avaiable notifications ...

What is the solution?

1. Downgrade api version. but I didn't find how i can downgrade version..

sorry I can't english well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t downgrade. It would not make any sense anyway, because sooner or later your App would stop working if you try to use stuff that is deprecated.

Anyway, access to notifications is not even available in older API versions anymore, because it is listed in `"90-day deprecations (effective Tuesday, October 6, 2015)"` - since that date, it´s no longer available anywhere.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog